# Linq to Entity Filter using Navigation Property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I would like to filter a Navigation Property in Entity Framework. From the examples given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ToList();
}
```

If I want to filter a particular blog and particular post, how can I filter? even if the post is not there the blog details must be returned

I want some thing like below

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
    .Where(b => b.BlogId == 1 && b.Posts.PostId == 2);
```

in the above case if the postid 2 is available for blogid 1 it should return both. If the blog is available then it should return only the blog details. How can I achieve this?

From SQL perspective it is like a Left Join.

Regards,
Joe

Comment: You can't do that with Entity Framework, you need to do 2 queries.

Comment: [DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) ?

Comment: @DavidG , Could you please send me any sample code on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A group join on two queries should work (the following assumes you want one post per blog, remove the FirstOrDefault() if that isn't the case):

```
var blogs = context.Blogs.Where(a => a.BlogId == 1);
var posts = context.Posts.Where(a => a.PostId == 2);


var blogWithPost = blogs.GroupJoin(posts, a => a.BlogId, a => a.PostId, (a,b) => new { Blog=a, Post = b.FirstOrDefault() });
```